# Gutenberg Blocks - Cannot retrieve block saved attributes in edit post

Tags: plugins, block-editor

After registering a new block in Gutenberg editor, it works fine until save /publish post, the output is fine in front end too, but after refreshing the edit screen, block shows the block validation error:

```
Content generated by `save` function:

Content retrieved from post body:
<div class="wp-block-gutenberg-examples-post-block3 slider-item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress_test/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/41QuqNH75-L.SY344_BO1204203200.jpg" dataid="146"/><img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress_test/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/41CoI-EUQML.SX258_BO1204203200.jpg" dataid="149"/></div>

Block validation: Block validation failed for `gutenberg-examples/post-block3`
```

This is how I register the new block:

```
blocks.registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/post-block3', {
    title: 'post: Controls',
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'common',

    attributes: {
        imgUrl: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'query',
            selector: '.slider-item',
            default: [],
            query:{
                mediaID: {
                    type: 'number',
                    source: 'attribute',
                    attribute: 'data-id',
                    selector: 'img',
                },
                mediaURL: {
                    type: 'string',
                    source: 'attribute',
                    attribute: 'src',
                    selector: 'img',
                },
            }
        },
    },

    edit: function( props ) {

        function selectImage(value) {

            props.setAttributes({
                imgUrl: value.map(function(val){return{mediaURL:val.url,mediaID:parseInt( val.id, 10 )}}),
            });
        }

        return el( Fragment, {className: props.className},
        el( InspectorControls, {},
        el( PanelBody, { title: 'Form Settings', initialOpen: true },
            el(MediaUpload,
                    {//onSelectImages
                        onSelect: selectImage,
                        multiple: true,
                        allowedTypes: 'image',
                        gallery:true,
                        value:props.attributes.imgUrl.map(function(val){
                            return val.mediaID;
                        }),
                        render(renderProps) {
                            return el('button',
                                {
                                    onClick: renderProps.open,
                                },
                                'upload image',
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    null
            ),

        ),),
      );
    },

    save: function( props ) {

        return el('div',{className: 'slider-item'},props.attributes.imgUrl.map(function(data){
            return el('img',
                        {
                            src: data.mediaURL,
                            'data-id':data.mediaID,
                        },
                        null
                    );
        }),
        );
    },
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block validation failed because the editor did not parse the attributes from all images (in the *saved* post content), and it's because your `save` function is returning only one `.slider-item` div containing multiple `img` tags, like so:

```html
<div class="slider-item">
    <img src="..." data-id="123" />
    <img src="..." data-id="456" />
    ...
</div>
```

And what should actually be returned is one or more `.slider-item` divs, each containing just one `img` tag, like so:

```html
<div class="slider-item">
    <img src="..." data-id="123" />
</div>
<div class="slider-item">
    <img src="..." data-id="456" />
</div>
...
```

[image: Visual illustration]

So make sure that your `save` function returns the correct markup based on your block attribute's definition. E.g.

```js
save: function( props ) {
    return el(
        'div',
        useBlockProps.save( {
            className: 'slider-items', // note the "itemS"
        } ),
        props.attributes.imgUrl.map( function ( data, i ) {
            return el(
                'div',
                {
                    className: 'slider-item',
                    key: 'slider-item-' + i,
                },
                el( 'img', {
                    src: data.mediaURL,
                    'data-id': data.mediaID,
                }, null )
            ); // end of .slider-item
        } ),
    ); // end of .slider-items
},
```

#### Additional Notes

1. `useBlockProps()` should be used in the `edit` function, and `useBlockProps.save()` in the `save` function.
2. When returning an ***array** of elements*, each of them should have a unique `key`.

So in the above example, I used `useBlockProps.save()` and `key`.

### References

- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#query
- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/
- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys